# Error in validation of an email

Tags: angular, validation

In my Angular4 application, I have made an input with type email.

```
<input type="email"   [(ngModel)]="email" class="form-control" id="email"
      pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$"       
      placeholder="Enter email" 
      name="email" required email
      #email="ngModel">
```

So, i want to show a message when the email is wrong.

```
<span style="color:red" class="help-block" *ngIf="!email.valid">The inserted Email is not valid</span>
```

So, the `#email` is the reference to the input in the line  `#email="ngModel"`.And then i check the validity with `*ngIf="!email.valid"`

But it complains with

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this part `[(ngModel)]="email"`. Here the word `email` refers to the template reference variable `#email` and not to your class property. Change some names so as to make them unique.

Comment: Hi, the ngModel reference should be unique application wide?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to offer you to use [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) instead of the usual ngModel.

Why is that ? Because reactive forms have **built-in validators**, and the mail is one of them. It's also much easier to create custom validators, than using ngModel.

Your code would become :

**HTML**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="mySubmit()">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required formControlName="email">
      <div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('email', ['email'])">Your mail is invalid</div>
      <div *ngIf="myForm.hasError('email', ['required'])">Your mail is required</div>
</form>
```

**Typescript**

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {JsonService} from './json.service';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'material-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 

  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private service: JsonService, private FB: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = FB.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]]
    });
  }
}
```